# C# LuaInterface How to get System.String from a Lua string

Tags: c#, luainterface

I recently started using LuaInterface in order to be able to run Lua scripts from a C# program. I wrote a test script which returns a string:

`````
teststring = "PRIVMSG #```` : SUCCESS!"
return testring
`````

I then try and add it to a C# Queue`<string`> by doing:

```
sendQueue.Enqueue(lua.DoFile(script).ToString());
```

However, this doesn't return a string. Instead, it returns System.Object[]. How do I get it to return System.String instead?

Comment: According to a comment here http://stackoverflow.com/questions/18197349/return-a-string-with-luainterface you probably only want the first item in the object array returned by lua. So, maybe you can try `sendQueue.Enqueue(lua.DoFile(script)[0].ToString());`. - Note the `[0]` which accesses the first item of a zero based array.

Comment: @Corak I'm now getting "System.NullReferenceException: Object reference not set to an instance of an object." at the Enqueue line. Different error, so that's probably progress!

Comment: Okay, looks like `lua.DoFile(script)` returns null... In the linked thread, they use `lua.DoString`, maybe that returns a valid string array (or a valid object array with a string as its first object).

Comment: @Corak Now I'm getting "LuaInterface.LuaException: [string "chunk"]:1: '=' expected near '\'" Except the script doesn't contain a '\' and I have no knowledge of Lua to understand what it's asking.

Comment: Sorry to not be of much more help, haven't used lua myself. A brief search returned this http://www.dreamincode.net/forums/topic/240886-integrating-lua-with-c%23-using-luainterface/ which doesn't deal with return values, but maybe for you something like `lua.DoFile(script); sendQueue.Enqueue((string)lua["teststring"]);` would work.

Comment: @Corak That would work, yes, but the eventual idea is to loop through a directory of Lua scripts and output what they return, which may not always be teststring. And you have been some help, so don't worry about it!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

A friend of mine managed to stumble upon the answer. In order to get it to produce an actual string, you should do the following:

```
var output = lua.DoFile(script).First().ToString();
Console.WriteLine(output);
sendQueue.Enqueue(output);
```

I don't understand why this method works, just that it does.